# Why wordpress plugin shortcode doesn't work properly with IE

Tags: plugins, php, javascript

I recently working on a wordpress, plugin, it already reached a final stage, and all it left is cross browser compatibility, the problem is why shortcode doesnt work properly With IE. Below are My code:

```
<?php 
    /*
    Plugin Name: Taggr
    Plugin URI: http://example.com/wordpress-plugins/my-plugin
    Description: Premium plugin for image and photo tagging
    Version: 1.0
    Author: Tee Kai Yang
    Author URI: http://wrox.com
    License: GPLv2
    */

    add_action('init', 'register_tagging_post');

     function register_tagging_post(){
       wp_enqueue_script('jquery2','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js');
     }

       $taggrArr = array();
     //add shortcode
     add_shortcode('taggr' , 'shortcode_func');
     function shortcode_func($attr){
       global $wpdb;
        global $post;
        $plugin_url = plugins_url();
        $taggrImageId = $attr['id'];
        $imageBaseName = $attr['name'];

        global $taggrArr;
        if(!isset($taggrArr["post". $post -> ID])){
           $taggrArr["post". $post -> ID] = 0;
         }
        $taggrArr["post". $post -> ID]++;

         $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM wp_taggr3 WHERE post_id = $taggrImageId";
        $rows_retrieve2 = $wpdb -> get_results($sql2, ARRAY_A);
        echo "<div style='position: relative;' id= 'wow".$post -> ID."'>";
        echo "<img src='http://www.billboard.com/files/styles/promo_650/public/stylus/2297459-katy-perry-outrageous-outfits-617-409.jpg' id ='img" . $taggrArr["post". $post -> ID]. "post" .$post -> ID . "'>";
        echo "<div style='position: absolute;' id= 'wiw".$post -> ID. "taggr". $taggrArr["post". $post -> ID]."'></div>";

         ?>
         <script>


             function woo1(){


                        var imageDisplay = document.getElementById('<?php echo "img" . $taggrArr["post". $post -> ID]. "post" . $post -> ID; ?>');
                        var polyShapeCount;
                        var localTaggrCount = <?php echo $taggrArr["post". $post -> ID]; ?>; 


                        $(imageDisplay).load(function(){
                         alert(this.id);


                             var imageDisplayShadow = document.getElementById('<?php echo "wiw" . $post -> ID; ?>taggr' + localTaggrCount);
                        imageDisplayShadow.style.width = imageDisplay.width + "px";
                        imageDisplayShadow.style.height = imageDisplay.height + "px";
                        imageDisplayShadow.style.top = "0px";
                        imageDisplayShadow.style.left = "0px";


                        var imageDisplayShadow1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
                        imageDisplayShadow1.style.width = "100%";
                        imageDisplayShadow1.style.height = "100%";
                        imageDisplayShadow1.style.top = "0px";
                        imageDisplayShadow1.style.left = "0px";
                        imageDisplayShadow1.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 100 100");
                        imageDisplayShadow1.setAttribute("preserveAspectRatio", "none");
                        imageDisplayShadow.appendChild(imageDisplayShadow1);




                             <?php
                            foreach($rows_retrieve2 as $row_retrieve2){
                                 if($row_retrieve2['tag_key'] == "tag"){
                                        $tag_value = unserialize($row_retrieve2['tag_value']);  
                                        if($tag_value['shape'] == "square"){
                             ?>

                                    var createTag = document.createElement("div");


                             <?php
                             }
                             }
                             }
                             ?>



                        });

            }

            woo1();
          </script>
           <?php
           echo "</div>";


     }



    ?>
```

This is the part where problem is, I created 4 different post with the taggr shortcode, by looking through this code, the page should alert four different types of image id, I tried it on firefox, chrome all works fine, but in Internet Explorer, it only shows 3 alerts can anybody tell me why??

Comment: I suppose it should be something in the javascript-code then. The serverbased code is not affected by which browser you're using.

Comment: but i cant find which code have problem

Comment: This isn't a WordPress question, as it's gonna be your JS that has the problem. Also, you shouldn't be re-enqueueing jQuery, that's just asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks, did you spotted any problem in my JS?

Comment: Check if <?php echo "img" . $taggrArr["post". $post -> ID]. "post" . $post -> ID; ?> is giving you correct value. I would bet this has something to do with slash/qutation-marks.